# Autocomplete polygon or autocomplete freehand in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, mac

Is there any similar function or plugins for QGIS as in ARCMAP for polygons called autocomplete polygon or autocomplete freehand. I am digitising polygons on a DEM as geomorphological research.  I need to digitise polygons next to each other with 0 overlap.

I'm a searching for this function in QGIS 3.4.9-Madeira on a Mac.

Comment: can you explain more what those functions do for those of us who don't use ArcMap

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, by activating the `Avoid intersection` in the `Snapping options` menu (found under `Project`).

[image]

Then just make a new polygon as shown in the left figure with red color. The result will be the yellow polygon in the right figure:
[image]

Comment: yes thak you!  you are correct

Comment: But one thing is missing is that same function but as free freehand polygon formations, is there Anything like that in QGIS?  Im not finding it in plugins..